# VLC: Unable to open SDP file for H265 using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, h.265

I am streaming live video using rtp and ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx265 -tune zerolatency -s 320x240 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 -strict experimental -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:49170 > ffmpeg.sdp
```

The generated sdp file is:

> ```
> v=0
> o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
> s=No Name
> c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
> t=0 0
> a=tool:libavformat 56.36.100
> m=video 49170 RTP/AVP 96
> a=rtpmap:96 H265/9000
> ```

Vlc gives the following error:

The format of 'file:///home/username/ffmpeg.sdp' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.

Terminal gives the following error:

```
[0xaf801010] ps demux error: cannot peek
[0xaf801010] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
[0xaf801010] mpgv demux error: cannot peek
[0xaf801010] ps demux error: cannot peek
[0xb6d00618] main input error: no suitable demux module for `file/:///home/username/ffmpeg.sdp'
```

If I simply change libx265 -> libx264 in the command and H265 -> H264 the stream runs perfectly fine.

However I need to stream on H265. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Support for `HEVC` over `RTP` was apparently added in both FFmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2014-September/163213.html) and VLC (https://patches.videolan.org/patch/4313/). The `ffmpeg` output  cannot be played even with `ffplay` so maybe there's some kind of regression. I deleted the my answer since it's clear the versions are not an issue.

Comment: Did you trying using the command I have posted? and replicate the scenario.

Comment: Yes, `ffplay` fails with `[hevc @ 0x7fe4f80049e0] Error parsing NAL unit #0.
[hevc @ 0x7fe4f80049e0] PPS id out of range: 00KB sq=    0B f=0/0  [sdp @ 0x7fb1a40008c0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[sdp @ 0x7fb1a40008c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
ffmpeg.sdp: could not find codec parameters
`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is because VLC (or ffplay) doesn't get the VPS,SPS,PPS frames.
In order to start to decode H265 stream you need a VPS, a SPS, a PPS and an IDR frame.

In order to ask to libx265 to repeat these configuration frames before each IDR frame you could add to your streaming command :

```
-x265-params keyint=30:repeat-headers=1
```

Then the command becomes :

```
ffmpeg -re -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx265 -tune zerolatency -x265-params keyint=30:repeat-headers=1 -s 320x240 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 -strict experimental -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:49170 > ffmpeg.sdp
```

It generate the following ffmpeg.sdp file:

```
SDP: 
v=0 
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 
s=No Name c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1 
t=0 0 
a=tool:libavformat 56.36.100 
m=video 49170 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H265/90000
```

I was able to display the stream with `ffplay ffmpeg.sdp` and `VLC ffmpeg.sdp` (removing the first line `SDP:` of `ffmpeg.sdp`)

Comment: v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 56.36.100
m=video 49170 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H265/90000

Comment: And I still was unable to play it.

Comment: Didn't work for me either way and I do remove "SDP:" form the file. Can you share with me your VLC version?

Comment: I use VLC `VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't shoot me down in flames, as I do not use VLC for this type of thing but I recall that to get Gstreamer working with H265, I had to install:
`libde265` and `gstreamer1.0-libde265`
There is also a `vlc-plugin-libde265` listed in the ubuntu repositories.
See: https://github.com/strukturag/libde265